# Jquery Accordion Additional Requirements

Tags: jquery, accordion

I need two ammendments in the following jquery code. [(DEMO is here)](http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/ePLzL/)

1. I want to slide up (hide) the paragraph when I click on close link inside the para.
2. Active class ( arrow icons) should work properly when I slide up/down any paragraph. If you noticed, arrows direction is getting crazy (∧ up, ∨ down, ∧ up) when I open both paragraphs. Arrow pointer should be downward (∨) when para is closed and if opened arrow should be pointed to upward (∧).

Following is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordion p").hide();

    $(".accordion h3").click(function(){
        $(this).next("p").slideToggle("fast")
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you if you want to open multiple paragraphs once.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordion p").hide();

    $(".accordion h3").click(function(){
        $(this).next("p").slideToggle("fast")
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });

    $(".mylink").click(function(){
        $(this).parent('p').prev().trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kishor_subedi/ePLzL/2/) for demo.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit more work I'm sure you'd do it soon by your own!

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ePLzL/1/)**</kbd>

```
$(function(){
    $(".accordion p").hide();

    $(".accordion h3").click(function(){
        $(this).next("p").slideToggle("fast").siblings('p').slideUp("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings("h3").removeClass("active");            
    });

    $('.accordion a.mylink').click(function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('p').slideToggle("fast").prev('h3').removeClass("active");        
    });
});
```